# Rails options_for_select data from model plus additional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of membership types as a constant in my model:

```
class Advisor < ActiveRecord::Base
  ACCOUNT_STATUSES = [ 'gold', 'bronze', 'silver', 'gold' ]
end
```

in my admin i have a table of all advisors and i have a sorting select box above the "Membership Type" column, so admin can select an account status and it will filter the table. But i need additional option called "All" and with value "all". Here is what i have so far:

```
<%= select_tag "search", options_for_select(["All", "all"] + Advisor::MEMBERSHIP_TYPES.collect{|m| [m.titleize, m]}) %>
```

But it creates a select box with two "All" options : "All" and "all" - i need "all" as a value...What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by wrapping ["All", "all"] in additional square brackets:

```
<%= select_tag "search", options_for_select([["All", "all"]] + Advisor::MEMBERSHIP_TYPES.collect{|m| [m.titleize, m]}) %>
```

Comment: You understand why, right? You need an array of arrays when you want to specify a value. So before you had ["All", "all", ["Gold", "gold"]...]